# Why don't the limits of integration matter when differentiating both sides of and equation?

Tags: calculus

Someone asked [this question:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22479/equation-with-a-definite-integral-can-i-differentiate-it) and I am very interested in the answer, but don't understand it and don't have enough reputation to comment on it directly.

The question asks if you can solve something like:
$$ g(x) = \int_a^b f(x) \,dx$$
by differentiating both sides, and then saying
$$g'(x) = f(x)$$.

The answerer says that you can ignore the $a$ and $b$ boundaries on the definite integral.  This is really convenient, but I don't understand why.  $\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$ is surely different than $\int_a^c f(x) \,dx$, where $b \neq c$.

Can anyone help me understand the intuition behind this?

Comment: It's not true that we can ignore the boundaries, and that's not what the answerer is saying. In what you've written, $a, b$ are constants, so if you differentiate both sides you get $g'(x) = 0$.

Comment: To elaborate on Zev's comment, it is misleading to write the equation as $g(x) = \int_{a}^b f(x) dx$. A better way is to write $g(x) = \int_a^b f(t) dt$, so that it becomes clear that the right hand side is a number, independent of $x$, $t$ and so on (they are called dummy variables). The integral in the other question is of the form: $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$. Now the right hand side is independent of $t$, but still dependent on $x$. So $g'(x)$ will not be zero in general.

Comment: Oh, I get it.  I re-read the original more closely -- it works in that case because the upper limit was a variable.  Sorry for the trouble!  This did help me figure it out though, so thank you.

Comment: So, there's no way to use differentiation to help solve a problem when there are definite integrals  (with constant limits)on both sides of the equality?..it will always reduce to just $0=0$ ?

Comment: @Anda: It only reduces to $0=0$ when you differentiate both sides; just like any equation reduces to $0=0$ if you multiply both sides by $0$, differentiating both sides of the equation, e.g.
$$5=7$$
loses information. There may be something else we can do that doesn't lose information. But really, an equation like 
$$\int_a^b x\,dx=\int_c^d \sqrt{x}\,dx$$
is only a *problem* if you want to try to solve for values of $c$ and $d$ (in terms of $a$ and $b$) that make it true; if you pick all of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ beforehand, it's just a statement, that is either true or false.

Comment: @Zev -- thanks.  My motivation is to see if I can determine whether such an equality is true or not.  The integrals are hard to compute, so I thought differentiating might get it into a form I could reduce to something obviously true or false.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you differentiate both sides of 
$$g(x) = \int_a^b f(x) \,dx$$
you get 
$$g'(x)=0$$
because 
$$\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$$
is **a number**. In the other question, the variable inside the integral is $\tau$ (tau), not $t$, the **variable** used as one of the limits of integration. Note that in the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part),
$$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \,dt\,$$
so $x$, the upper limit of the integral, is the *input* to the function $F$, and $x$ is the variable that we differentiate against.

Comment: @Anda In the general case, where the limits depend on $x$ and also the function $f(t)$ depends on $x$ (i.e., it is really $h(x,t)$), one should apply the more general formula given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign).

Answer (score 4):

It might help to point out that, if your equation is
$$f(x) = \int_x^b g(t) dt$$
then $f'(x) = - g(x)$. So the limits certainly matter. (Challenge: if $f(x) = \int_x^{2x} g(t) dt$, what is $f'(x)$?)

Comment: I think the answer should be g(2x)-g(x)?

Comment: @lopi: close, but you're missing a part of the chain rule.